# Java not returning entire HTML string, only a portion of it

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to scrape some data from a web page for an android application.  The problem is that when I pull in the HTML from the page, I only get a small portion of the page, not the whole thing.  When I go to the actual page in Chrome, press F12, I see way more code than this Java method returns.

Here is my code to get the HTML string:

```
        System.setProperty("http.agent", USER_AGENT);
        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpGet get = null;
        HttpClient client = null;
        String s = "";
        try {
            if (client == null) {
                client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            }
            get = new HttpGet(URL_LOG_MAIN);
            response = client.execute(get);
            s = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return s;
```

and I have these hard coded constants:

```
    private static final String URL_LOG_MAIN = "https://changelog.omnirom.org/";
    private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla//5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.10) Gecko//2009042316 Firefox//3.0.10 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
```

Comment: Are you sure, on the browser, it doesn't contain HTML that is generated by javascript?

Comment: When you use a command-line utility, like **`curl`** or **`wget`**, to retrieve this URL, what do you get? If you get the same "small portion of the page", then the problem is not with Android, but with how that page is constructed.

Comment: The portions of the page that I am missing are most likely generated by JavaScript since the page is very dynamic and is updated anytime the teams Github repo changes.  Would there be a way to invoke the script that is generating the parts that I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The portions of the page that I am missing are generated by JavaScript since the page is very dynamic and is updated anytime the teams Github repo changes.